# Database tables are not getting shown in the generated PDF file

Tags: android, pdf, itext, itextg

I am trying to generate a report in PDF format in which data is coming from Sqlite Database.I am using itextg library for generating PDF. But the problem is ,the generated pdf file shows only below content.

> 1.Expense Report
>
> Report Generated on Tue Mar 07 17:50:43 GMT +05:30 2017

data which i am fetching from sqlite database is not getting shown Can somebody help me with issue which i am not able to identify.

Below is my Code:

```
public class GenerateReport extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

int date1, date2;
Cursor c;

private static Font catFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 18,
        Font.BOLD);
private static Font redFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12,
        Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.RED);
private static Font subFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 16,
        Font.BOLD);
private static Font smallBold = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12,
        Font.BOLD);
private static String FILE;
Button bpdf;
int counter = 0;
static ArrayList<String> category; 
static ArrayList<String> mode;
static ArrayList<Integer> amount;
static ArrayList<String> date;

View backg;
// You can access the static variables from nonstatic methods


private TextView text_date1, text_date2,tv_date1,tv_date2;
private DatePicker date_picker1, date_picker2;
private Button bstart_date, bend_date;

private int year1, year2;
private int month1, month2;
private int day1, day2;

static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID1 = 100;
static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID2 = 200;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.generate_report);
    backg = findViewById(R.drawable.words_bgred);
    loadPreference();
    if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        // sd card mounted
    }

    File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/ExpenseManager");

    if (!direct.exists()) {
        if (direct.mkdir()) {
            // directory is created;
        }

    }

    bpdf = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bpdf_gen);
    bpdf.setOnClickListener(this);
    bpdf.setEnabled(false);



    setCurrentDate();
    addButtonListener1();
    setEndDate();
    addButtonListener2();


}



private static void addContent(Document document) throws DocumentException {

    Anchor anchor = new Anchor("Expense Report", catFont);
    anchor.setName("Expense Report");


    Chapter catPart = new Chapter(new Paragraph(anchor), 1);

    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
    paragraph.add(new Paragraph("Report generated on " + new Date(),
            smallBold));

    addEmptyLine(paragraph, 3);

    catPart.add(paragraph);


    createTable(catPart);


    document.add(catPart);

    Log.e("meta", "content");

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
finish();

}


private void vibrate(int ms) {
    ((Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE)).vibrate(ms);
}

private static void createTable(Section catPart) throws BadElementException {
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(4);


    for (int i = 0; i < category.size(); i++) {
        Log.e("category...", category.get(i));
        Log.e("mode...", mode.get(i));
        Log.e("amt...", "amt" + amount.get(i));
        Log.e("date2...", "date" + date.get(i));
    }

    PdfPCell c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Category Name"));
    c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    table.addCell(c1);

    c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Amount Spent (Rs)"));
    c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    table.addCell(c1);

    c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Date"));
    c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    table.addCell(c1);

    c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Payment Mode"));
    c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    table.addCell(c1);

    table.setHeaderRows(1);

    for (int i = 0; i < category.size(); i++) {
        table.addCell(category.get(i));
        table.addCell(amount.get(i) + "");
        table.addCell(date.get(i));
        table.addCell(mode.get(i));

    }

    catPart.add(table);
    Log.e("meta", "table");

}

private static void addEmptyLine(Paragraph paragraph, int number) {
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        paragraph.add(new Paragraph(" "));
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {

//  vibrate(50);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        category = new ArrayList<String>();
        mode = new ArrayList<String>();
        amount = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        date = new ArrayList<String>();

        if (date1 > date2) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Start Date should be less than End Date",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e("date1", date1 + " " + date2);

        }

        else {

            DbClass dc = new DbClass(this);
            dc.open();
            c = dc.showResultInPdf(date1, date2);
            for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {


                category.add(c.getString(1));
                mode.add(c.getString(4));
                amount.add(c.getInt(2));




                String change = c.getString(3);

                change = change.substring(0, 8);

                Log.e("change", change);
                date.add(change);

            }


            dc.close();
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    "Pdf Report Generated and saved in \n "
                            + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                    .getAbsolutePath() + "/ExpenseManager",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

            int year_current = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month_current = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
            int day_current = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            String print = day_current + "-" + month_current + "-"
                    + year_current;

            savePreference();
            FILE = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/ExpenseManager/ExpenseManager" + " " + print + "("
                    + counter + ")" + ".pdf";
            Document document = new Document();
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(FILE));
            document.open();

            addContent(document);
            document.close();

        }

    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void savePreference() {
    counter++;
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("AppSharedPref", 0);
    Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putInt("count", counter);
    editor.commit();

}

private void loadPreference() {
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("AppSharedPref", 0);
    counter = sp.getInt("count", 0);

}


public void setCurrentDate() {

    text_date1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_date1);
    tv_date1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date_label1);
    date_picker1 = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.date_picker1);

    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    year1 = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month1 = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day1 = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


    text_date1.setText(new StringBuilder()

            .append(day1).append("/").append(month1 + 1).append("/")
            .append(year1).append(" "));


    date_picker1.init(year1, month1, day1, null);
    String s = new StringBuilder().append(year1).append(month1 + 1)
            .append(day1).toString();


    date1 = Integer.parseInt(s);


}


public void setEndDate() {

    text_date2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_date2);
    tv_date2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date_label2);
    date_picker2 = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.date_picker2);

    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    year2 = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month2 = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day2 = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // set current date into textview
    text_date2.setText(new StringBuilder()
            // Month is 0 based, so you have to add background1
            .append(day2).append("/").append(month2 + 1).append("/")
            .append(year2).append(" "));

    // set current date into Date Picker
    date_picker2.init(year2, month2, day2, null);

    String s = new StringBuilder().append(year2).append(month2 + 1)
            .append(day2).toString();


    date2 = Integer.parseInt(s);


}

public void addButtonListener1() {

    bstart_date = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bstart_date);

    bstart_date.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID1);

        }

    });

}

public void addButtonListener2() {

    bend_date = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bend_date);
    bend_date.setEnabled(false);

    bend_date.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID2);

        }

    });
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

    if (id == DATE_DIALOG_ID1) {
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener1, year1,
                month1, day1);
    }

    else if (id == DATE_DIALOG_ID2) {
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener2, year2,
                month2, day2);
    }
    return null;

}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener1 = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
            int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
        year1 = selectedYear;
        month1 = selectedMonth + 1;
        day1 = selectedDay;

        // set selected date into Text View
        text_date1.setText(new StringBuilder().append(day1).append("/")
                .append(month1).append("/").append(year1).append(" "));
        text_date1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tv_date1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        // set selected date into Date Picker
        date_picker1.init(year1, month1, day1, null);
        String s = year1 + "" + (month1 < 10 ? ("0" + month1) : (month1))
                + "" + (day1 < 10 ? ("0" + day1) : (day1));


        date1 = Integer.parseInt(s);

        bend_date.setEnabled(true);

    }
};

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener2 = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
            int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
        year2 = selectedYear;
        month2 = selectedMonth + 1;
        day2 = selectedDay;


        text_date2.setText(new StringBuilder().append(day2).append("/")
                .append(month2).append("/").append(year2).append(" "));
        text_date2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tv_date2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        date_picker2.init(year2, month2, day2, null);
        String s = year2 + "" + (month2 < 10 ? ("0" + month2) : (month2))
                + "" + (day2 < 10 ? ("0" + day2) : (day2));

        date2 = Integer.parseInt(s);


        bpdf.setEnabled(true);


    }
};
```

Comment: create pdf writer to write into new document PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(FILE));

     
     document.open();   and have you declared permission in manifest

Comment: @peter  i have already made an instance of pdfwriter in the above code, and i have already given the permission for read and write external storage in manifest. Is there anyother permission which i should declare in manifest ?

Comment: Your PDF creation code is spread out so wide and depends on externally given data that it cannot be used to try and reproduce the issue. Please try to reduce the code to concentrate on the task of PDF creation (no UI event handling necessary for that) based on static texts.

Comment: @mkl  the pdf generation part is now ok sir, but now the problem is the data which i am fetching from database is not coming in the pdf file.

Comment: And what do the log outputs say?

Comment: @mkl  logcat doesn't show anything its just printing meta and content nothing after that

Comment: *its just printing meta and content* - by content do you mean the output of the logging loop at the start of `createTable`?

Comment: @mkl no its just two words "meta" and "Content" are getting printed as in my code they are mentioned like " log.e("meta", "table") "

Comment: @mkl  in the pdf not even table structure is getting printed leave the data from database aside, which means nothing is getting printed except the two lines which i have mentioned in my question explanation.

Comment: If I *leave the data from database aside*, i.e. if there is no data in `category`, there obviously will be no table: if itext has a table with only header lines, no data, itext does not draw the table at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the tables were not getting created properly thats why data was not getting saved into the pdf.

Comment: Do you mean the *database* tables were not getting created properly?

Comment: yes,, this code was fine  problem was in database code.